# jsdom тест на e.currentTarget.innerText дает undefined как добится того что бы там было значение

Tags: reactjs, jest, react-testing-library

Итак, кратко: насколько я понял тестовая среда jsDom не поддерживает innerText.(также возможно много чего другово)

Проблема: я не хочу менять код что бы подстроится под jsDom. (Код то рабочий...)

**например:**

<del>setText(e.currentTarget.innerText);</del>

```
setText(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
```

я хочу что бы jsDom умел работать с innerText(просто не знаю что еще не будет работать в далнейшем...)

```js
//тест
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("renders learn react link", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  const button = screen.getByRole("button");

  // v:13
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(button).toHaveTextContent("base"); //get undefined
});

//компонент
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("base");
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          setText(e.currentTarget.innerText);
        }}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```